# find the top right corner with black pixel usind a grid

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

i have this page and i am trying to make a cropped image with the top right corner
i used this code for the top left corner with black pixel inside but could not edit it to work for top right.it makes a grid .if the square inside has black pixels is number 1 else is 0. it find the top left square with black pixels and crop around it.

input

> [image: input.jpg]

output

> [image: output.jpg]

I am trying to auto-crop this page number area

> [image: what i wanna auto-crop]

I think the script search from like the blue arrow and i want to work like the red

> [image: how i think it search.jpg]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the cropped image in grayscale
image = cv2.imread('input.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Get the height and width of the image
h, w = image.shape

# Define the number of rows and columns of the grid
rows = 30
cols = 40

# Calculate the size of each square in pixels
square_h = h // rows
square_w = w // cols

# Create an empty array to store the grid values
grid = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=int)

# Loop over the rows and columns of the grid
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        # Get the coordinates of the top left corner of the square
        x = j * square_w
        y = i * square_h

        # Get the sub-image corresponding to the square
        square = image[y:y+square_h, x:x+square_w]

        # Check if the square contains any black pixels
        if np.any(square < 255):
            # Set the grid value to 1
            grid[i, j] = 1

# Find the top left corner with a 1 square
# Use np.argwhere to get the indices of the nonzero elements
# Use np.min to get the minimum row and column index
top_left = np.min(np.argwhere(grid == 1), axis=0)

# Get the row and column index of the top left corner
row, col = top_left

# Define the number of squares to crop around the corner
crop_size = 3

# Get the coordinates of the top left corner of the cropped region
x = col * square_w
y = row * square_h

# Get the sub-image corresponding to the cropped region
cropped_image = image[y:y+crop_size*square_h, x:x+crop_size*square_w]

# Save the result
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', cropped_image)
```

could not work for top right corner

Comment: You could rotate the image -90 degrees and reduce the whole thing to a row, then search for the first black pixels - that's your horizontal coordinate.

Comment: i am trying to create an auto-crop page number detect . that it will be for any book page format.page number could be anywhere .even if i rotate for many format is left or right depend if its add or even page ,or to the bottom .   it is for a diybookscanner project . the logic of the grid can also help to crop the content without the margin. i think also program like scantailor use this logic.

Comment: casually, most books will have a larger vertical dimension, which you could flip to, then rotate back, though that strategy is obviously too simplistic for the general case, it may work with more heuristics, such as adding random horizontal lines and counting meeting adjacent pixels or successful OCR rate on a subset of pages and then assuming all other pages have that rotation

Comment: i also  made something on python like take a bunch of specific orient images images (like the one i uploaded) 
 rotate 90 degrees

for a loop -5 +5 degress keep the the results on a array
  ocr only numbers at each page on the top first 1/8 of the image 
keep the most common number u read.

now the staff above  could work faster if i have small cropped images not all the image from the page. 
ok in the end i just crop around the page number a big area with also text from the book .but in autocrop if u add 30 more pattern it work for a format of a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figure out what i wanted i think i find how to detect page number from a page

this is the black n white page on the top right is the pattern i want to crop ,this match with page number from multiple even pages ,the one i uploaded input.jpg is an example image

```
output.txt
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000#0#######################0#####################00##00000
000##0##############################################0##00000
000#################################################00000000
000#################################################00000000
000#################################################00000000
000#################################################00000000
000#################################################00000000
000#################################################00000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000##################################################0000000
000####################################################00000
000####################################################00000
000####################################################00000
000####################################################00000
000####################################################00000
000####################################################00000
000####################################################00000
000###0#######################0########################00000
000###0#######################0########################00000
000###0#######################0########################00000
000###0#######################0#####################0##00000
000###0#######################0#####################0##00000
000###0#######################0#####################0##00000
000###0#######################00########0###########0##00000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
####0000000000000000000000000000#00####00#0###000#00########
############################################################
00#0##0##0###000000000#0##000000#########00000##0000000#0000
00#0#0#0#0#000#00#000#00##00000##########000#00##0##00#00000
0###0#00###0##00#000####000#0#00###################00#000000
0#00##00####0#000000##00###0000#######0########0######000000
```

this is the pattern i will try to crop here is on top right

```
0000
0##0
0##0
0000
0000
```

this is the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the cropped image in grayscale
image = cv2.imread('input.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Get the height and width of the image
h, w = image.shape

# Define the number of rows and columns of the grid
rows = 45
cols = 60

# Calculate the size of each square in pixels
square_h = h // rows
square_w = w // cols

# Create an empty array to store the grid values
grid = np.empty((rows, cols), dtype=str)

# Loop over the rows and columns of the grid
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        # Get the coordinates of the top left corner of the square
        x = j * square_w
        y = i * square_h

        # Get the sub-image corresponding to the square
        square = image[y:y+square_h, x:x+square_w]

        # Check if the square contains any black pixel
        if np.any(square < 255):
            # Set the grid value to '#'
            grid[i, j] = '#'
        else:
            # Set the grid value to '0'
            grid[i, j] = '0'

# Write the result to output.txt
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            file.write(grid[i, j])
        file.write('\n')

# Pattern matching
pattern = [
    '0000',
    '0##0',
    '0##0',
    '0000',
    '0000'
]

with open("output.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()

lines = content.split('\n')

for i in range(len(lines) - len(pattern) + 1):
    for j in range(len(lines[i]) - len(pattern[0]) + 1):
        match = True
        for k in range(len(pattern)):
            if lines[i + k][j:j+len(pattern[0])] != pattern[k]:
                match = False
                break
        if match:
            print(f"Pattern found at line {i+1}, position {j+1}")

            # Crop the region where the pattern is found
            x_start = j * square_w
            y_start = i * square_h
            x_end = (j + len(pattern[0])) * square_w
            y_end = (i + len(pattern)) * square_h

            cropped_image = image[y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end]

            # Save the cropped image
            cv2.imwrite('cropped_page_number.jpg', cropped_image)
```

> [image: cropped_page_number.jpg]
> thanks for your comments